# Trying to speed up a SQL query

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures, inner-join

I'm still in the process of getting to fully understand SQL Server. I have wrote a stored procedure as shown below:

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[Specific_Street_Lookup]
    @STR Varchar(50),
    @CNT int
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT DISTINCT TOP (@CNT) 
       street_desc, street_localitydesc, postcode_selected
   FROM 
       Full_Streets 
   INNER JOIN 
       Postcodes ON Full_Streets.street_postcodeid = postcodes.postcode_id
   WHERE 
       street_desc LIKE @STR+'%' 
       AND postcode_selected = 'TRUE'
  ORDER BY 
       street_desc, street_localitydesc
END
```

but it can take up to 7 seconds to return a result, I'm not sure what I can do to speed up the query.

- The `full_street` table has a row count of 856800
- The `postcode` table has a row count of 856208

Both tables have a primary key (`street_id` & `postcode_id`)

The purpose of the query: in my VB.net app as the user is typing in a street to look up it return a number of records (`@CNT`) that match the partial string (`LIKE @STR'+%'`) and only if `postcode_selected = 'TRUE'`

I'm sure there must be a quicker / better way to do this and any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you create index for `street_desc` and `postcode_selected` as combined index and try the query?

Comment: Hi Arindam, thanks for the quick reply. How do I create a combined index? Do I do this through the table design or actually within the stored procedure?

Comment: right click on index option in left pane (shown by expanding table) and select those columns for that index, give a name, and save, then rebuild index, and execute sp.

Comment: Thanks, not wanting to sound like a idiot here but when I expand my postcodes table I have an **indexes** folder, right click gives me new index option and within that I can only select **non-clustered index** (the rest are greyed out) is this the right one? For some reason when I do the same procedure on my full_streets table and right click on Indexes the new index option is greyed out. Any idea why this might be? I'm logged in as sa. Thanks for your help with this.

Comment: Which column Belongs to which table?

Comment: yes, that would be non-clustered index only as clustered ones are for primary keys only, not sure why you got greyed out option in 2nd table.
One more note, turn on `Actual Execution plan` and see which part of query is running slow, tune that one.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. Following what Steve has said I have now created two new indexes, one for full_streets table which has been named IX_Full_Streets and is assigned to column Street_desc. Also on postcodes table I have created IX_Postcodes assign to column postcode_selected. So I assume that I just rebuild indexes and retry my query?

Answer (score 2):

Can you try with this index?

```
CREATE INDEX NCI_street_desc ON Full_Streets(street_desc) INCLUDE(street_localitydesc)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply. Does this create index line go into the stored procedure? if so is it after the BEGIN statement?

Comment: Don't add this script inside the stored procedure.Run it separately and then only execute the procedure.

Comment: Thanks I did that, on my machine the query comes back fast, no problem. on the client machine (I've made all the same changes) it has only slightly improved. The main differences between the two machines is my has an SSD drive where the other has an IDE drive. So I'm thinking if the query can't get any quicker software wise I can upgrade the client PC with an SSD. Even though this does seem an expensive way to quicken the query :)

Comment: @RichardSpademan, is the execution plan the same on your machine the same as on the client's box?  You might try adding OPTION(RECOMPILE) as the best plan will vary depending on the value specified.

Answer (score 0):

The LIKE operator is evil in such a big table, and I don't think you can optimize this query with normal indexes.

Consider using Full Text Search functionalities. With full text search you can't search portions of strings (unless you make a special table where you pre-save all the possible portions of your strings) but performance are hugely superior than what you can achieve using the LIKE operator.

Answer (score 0):

I would change postcode_selected column type to bit (TRUE = 1, FALSE = 0) and then modify sp accordingly - it will reduce time complexity of the query.